# Git: import from multiple bitbucket repo to single repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Actually i have three projects in different bitbucket repos in my private account i have to transfer it to single  github.com repository.I want to import all projects from my private account to different branches without loss of my all commits of different project.How to do it.

Comment: different repos have to be become different branches of one new repo? what is the point of doing that, do you understand why branches are used for, and how are you going to merge them later?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new local repository (`git init threeprojects`).
- Add all three bitbucket repos (`git remote add remote1 url1` etc.)
- Fetch everything (`git fetch --all`)
- Create branches (`git branch project1 remote1/master` etc.)
- Add the github repository (`git remote add github url`)
- Push all three branches (`git push --all github`)

If you want to explicitely keep other branches from the original repositories, create them locally as needed. If there are many, you can automate it by parsing the output of `git branch -a` in a little shell script. It should be obvious how to do that similar to the commands given above; do ask if it is not.